# Strange Error on Function Entry Point using OpenCV and VLC SDK

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, linker, vlc

I am trying to implement a Video Caputre that uses the VLC SDK and OpenCV, so that I could use the better streaming handling from VLC in an OpenCV project.
I have build a static Library A that contains the CVLCVideoCaputre class. This library includes the vlc/vlc.h and also the cv.h. It build successfully.

When I want to implement this Library A in and application. I link the libvlc.lib and libvlccore.lib and also the OpenCV libraries dynamicaly. Also this project is build.

But by running the programm I got the following error:

"The Function Entry Point: "?create@Mat@cv@@QAEXHPBHH@Z" was not found in the DLL "libvlc.dll" (Translation from German) "

Its stange because this function is in "opencv_core231.dll".

Has anybody an idea why the cv::Mat::create function is associated to the wrong lib and how I could fix that.

I am using Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's a runtime problem... Your custom library seems to have dependencies and these can't be fulfilled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the solution was to set a Linker Flag to /OPT:NOREF which is not optimizing your references. You could find this in the Visual Studio Settings by:

Configuration Properties->Linker->Optimization->References